# Best/fastest way to copy over large amounts of RTF data to a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, richtextbox, stringbuilder

So I do a ton of RTF manipulations in a `StringBuilder` and that works great, its in a loop and takes like 0.02 seconds even for a ton of results.  So now that I have the RTF data I want and I need to place it in the `RichTextBox`.  It turns out the simple operation of:

```
tempRTB.Rtf = strRTF.ToString(); //strRTF is the StringBuilder
```

is the time hog (22 seconds in this example).  This is particularly frustrating because I finally found a super fast way to generate the RTF and now copying it over is what takes forever haha.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that strRTF.ToString() is sufficiently fast. The RTF property of the RichTextBox is probably parsing the string, and creating some internal document structure, which is taking lots of time. You can prove this with profiling or adding timing code pretty easily. Unfortunately if my assumption is true, I'm not sure what you can do to increase the performance of the RTF property.

Comment: You're correct, I replaced it with `string temp = strRTF.ToString();` just to see and it took like .04 seconds... sounds like I might be out of luck huh?

Comment: Possibly. It might be worth investigating other formats. HTML is usually pretty fast.

Comment: Is there a winforms control for that? Or would I have to go custom?

Comment: Check out the WebBrowser control. It basically wraps an Internet Explorer window.